# Aptos-sdk | How to decode a hexString into a human readable string

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, aptos

I am currently trying to get the information of the fields network_addresses  and fullnode_addresses in the validator set. (i got the info from this api resquest call, json there https://aptos-vfn.stakely.io/v1/accounts/0x1/resource/0x1::stake::ValidatorSet)

The problem is that i am not able to get the clean string from the data. I got a string with many strange characters

Here is what one of the last codes i tried.

any more help please?

```
const aptos = require('aptos');

xx = new aptos.HexString("0x014404021a6170746f732d76616c696461746f722e7374616b656c792e696f0524180720796e34b3ffbd8396ad4ade8e397420bad3b5c49dee20a1dbcf8e6256105a1a2a0800");

yy = xx.toUint8Array();


let bb = new aptos.BCS.Serializer();

bb.serializeBytes(yy);
cc = bb.getBytes();

c = new aptos.BCS.Deserializer(cc);

ee = c.deserializeStr();


console.log("RESULT:", ee);
```

and the result is this string with those strange chars...

> RESULT: ☺D♦☻→aptos-validator.stakely.io♣$↑ yn4������Jގ9t �ӵĝ� ��ώbV►Z→*

any help to decode this into human readable string?

thanks

An human readable encoding string, without strange characters